# How many four digit numbers have this property?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many four digit numbers are multiples of 3 but not the multiples of 2 or 5 or multiples of 2 but not the multiples of 3 or 5 or multiples of 5 but not the multiples of 2 or 3?

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe try to count the single or double digits first, see if you can spot a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You should prove it using the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

Let's calculate how many 4 digits number are multiples of 2 but not multiples of 3 and 5.

There are $\frac{9998-1000}{2} + 1=4500$ 4 digits numbers that are multiples of 2

There are $\frac{9996-1002}{6} + 1=1500$ 4 digits numbers that are multiples of 2 and 3

There are $\frac{9990-1000}{10}+ 1=900$ 4 digits numbers that are multiples of 2 and 5

There are $\frac{9990-1020}{30} + 1=300$ 4 digits numbers that are multiples of 2, 3 and 5

There fore there are $4500 - 1500 - 900 + 300 = 2400$ 4 digits number are multiples of 2 but not multiples of 3 and 5.

Do the same for 3 and 5.

Comment: I get the same answer as you do, but I'm curious: Where does $9998, 9996$ and $9990$ come from?

Comment: if you want to find all the 4 digits numbers that are devided by 2, you take the smallest such number (which is 1000) and the biggest (which is 9998) and devide the substraction of them by the wanted number (which is 2). You should do the same for 2 and 3 (means, 6), 2 and 5 (means, 10), and 2,3 and 5 (means, 30).

Comment: According to that method there are $4$ one-digit numbers divisible by $2$: $\frac{8-0}{2}$, but there are five ($0,2,4,6,8$).

Comment: forgot to add 1. thank you. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are $9000$ four-digit numbers. Half of them, i.e. $4500$ are divisible by $2$. Of these, again, a third ($4500/3 = 1500$) are divisible by $3$, and a fifth ($4500/5 = 900$) are divisible by $5$, so we subtract each of those to get $2100$. However, the numbers that are divisible by *both* three and five at the same time (i.e. divisible by $15$, there are $300$ of those) were subtracted *twice* when we only wanted to subtract them once, so we need to counter that by adding $300$ back. Therefore there are $2400$ four-digit numbers that are divisible by $2$, and at the same time not divisible by neither $3$ nor $5$. (This way of counting, by subtracting each of them and adding back what was double-counted, is called the *inclusion-exclusion principle*, and it some times makes seemingly difficult counting easy.)

The two other cases are done exactly the same way to get $1200$ for $3$ and $600$ for $5$. Add all those together to get the final answer of $4200$.

Comment: I think you miscalculated. It's actually 1200 numbers for 3 and 600 for 5, leading to a total of 4200.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yeah, for some reason I got $200$ for the all-divisor sets when doing those two.